# How to include dhcpv6 option37 info

Tags: networking, ipv6, dhcp

Dhcpv6 packages ask include option37 REMOTE_ID date.
Command: dhclient
Config file: dhclient.conf

Question

1. What phase solicit or request should include?
2. How to enable/config option37?

Reference:

option37 [syntax](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/option-37-edit-dhcp-security.html).

```
option-37 {
prefix {
host-name;
logical-system-name;
routing-instance-name;
vlan-id;
vlan-name;
}
use-interface-index (device | logical);
use-interface-description (device | logical);
use-interface-mac;
use-interface-name (device | logical);
use-string string;
}
```

2.Huawei about [option37 info](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000177810/45dccf37/dhcpv6--option18--option37--enable).

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution.
way 1:

Modify /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf. Include option 37.

way2:

ebtables add a extensions dhcpv6snoop function.Insert -t nat prerouting & postrouting.

That's will autofill add option37.

Comment: None of that has anything to do with programming. You seem to have asked on the wrong SE site. This question would be more appropriate on [sf].